# How to compare two b2body objects?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

```
 b2Body *relatedBody = (b2Body *)[relatedBodiesValue pointerValue];
for(b2MouseJoint *joint = (b2MouseJoint *)relatedBody->GetJointList(); joint; joint = (b2MouseJoint *)joint->GetNext())
                {
                    if((b2Body *)joint->GetUserData() == _touchedBody)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"OK");
                    }
                }
```

Is this right way to compare two b2body objects?

Comment: If you are asking whether you can compare bodies by pointer: yes, you can.

Comment: Yes. Although I would add, it's safer not to cast to a b2MouseJoint* in the loop, in case the joints are not mouse joints.